# Could someone explain me what this mean line by line?

Tags: javascript

1. This is code.js from my tutorial
2. I need help with my homework:

   ```
   var buttonRef2 = document.getElementById('toggle');
   buttonRef2.onclick = function () {
       var state = document.getElementById('wikiList').style.display;
       var txt = document.getElementById('toggle').textContent;
       if(state == 'none' && txt == 'show' ) {
           document.getElementById('wikiList').style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById('toggle').textContent = 'hide';
           document.getElementById('toggle').classList.add('extraStyle');
       }else{
           document.getElementById('wikiList').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('toggle').textContent = 'show';
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: what I know so far... not much..

Comment: Then I would start to google around, and see if you can figure out what they do by looking through documentation.

Comment: By the way, I suggest you to [properly format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) while asking a question like this :)

Comment: What is your homework? "Understand this" or what?

Comment: I have used Google for you: [var](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp), [getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp), [onClick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp), [function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp), [style.display](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp), [textContent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp), [if-else statament](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Comment: Get familiar with running Javascript in the browser debugging tools (e.g. Chrome's developer tools) which will let you step through the code.  And doing a google search to get documentation on the function calls.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to answer this question for you, since it's your homework, but I can point you in the right direction so you can work it out for yourself.

[Document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) docs is a good point to start. Consider the string that is being passed to this function (i.e 'toggle') and what this means.

The object that is returned from `getElementById(id)` is an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). If you look through the property list, you should recognise a lot of the properties that you've supplied there.

If there's anything that you get stuck on, remember that you can always search on the internet. The MDN (the website that my links point to) is a really good place to find out about these sorts of things.

Comment: Thanks, anyone, I think I can try to do it myself... little panic moment

Answer (score 0):

```
    var buttonRef2 = document.getElementById('toggle'); //Looking for an ID called 'toggle' on the page and assign it to the variable 'buttonRef2'

    buttonRef2.onclick = function () { //add onclick event to the previously declared variable so it can run the function 
    var state = document.getElementById('wikiList').style.display; //find the 'wikilist' ID's style.display property and assign it to variable 'state'. This way you save extra DOM search

    var txt = document.getElementById('toggle').textContent; //grab the textcontent from the element with the ID of 'toggle'and assign to txt varaible

    if(state == 'none' && txt == 'show' ) { //&& operator - checks if the block is hidden(none) and if the txt varaible has a value of 'show'
//if the above condition is met you are going to execute the next lines of code.
    document.getElementById('wikiList').style.display = 'block'; // change the css property of display to 'block' this will show the element if it's been hidden away
document.getElementById('toggle').textContent = 'hide'; // change the text of the toggle element to 'hide' 
document.getElementById('toggle').classList.add('extraStyle'); // add another css class called 'extraStyle' to the element with an ID of 'toggle'
    }
    else{ // else block if the above if statement criteria weren't met
    document.getElementById('wikiList').style.display = 'none'; // hide the 'wikilist' element
document.getElementById('toggle').textContent = 'show'; // change the text content to 'show' } }
```

Comment: You could write a line of code to see what something returns like below.
console.log(state);
console.log(txt); 
Then if you open the chrome console you can see what they return. Hope this helps. Good luck with your paper.